# Best Lua OOP library

Tags: oop, lua

What is the best Lua OOP library in terms of speed, syntax convenience, LOC and license? Thank you.

I've found LOOP. http://loop.luaforge.net/index.html It offers pretty nice syntax:

```
local oo = require "loop.base" local
Date = oo.class
{
   -- default field values
   day   = 1,   month = 1,  year  = 1900,
}

local birthday = Date {} -- instance
```

But I do not like the license.

And: http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectLua

Comment: What's the problem with the license? LOOP uses the MIT license, which is the same one Lua uses.

Comment: The best choice is to find simple fast code in public domain and remaster it, so no license with execution files will be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend checking out http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectOrientedProgramming. It has links to the most popular Lua OOP libraries and instructions on how to roll your own if necessary. The latter seems to be a very popular choice.